# How to read string parameters and forms data from a url Aspnet WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

**1 - I generate a Link from a WebApi Controller passing two parameters with:**

```
var URL = new Uri( Url.Link("Default", new { Controller = "Reset", Action = 
"ResetPassword",user = "AAAAA", hash = "HASHVALUE" }));
```

And I get this:

```
http://localhost:52494/Reset/ResetPassword?user=BBBBBBBB&hash=AAAAAAA
```

**2 - I need to Read these two parameters and the Form as well.**

So I have a controller `Reset` with a `ResetPassword` Action:

```
public ActionResult ResetPassword()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(Models.ResetUserModel user)
{
   var HASH = Request["hash"];     
   var id = Request["user"];
   return View();
}
```

And the cshtml file:

[image]

If I run this page and fill the form, I will be able to read the `ResetUserModel`, but if it has some parameter, the model comes null!!

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: it seems like the link is a Get request, while you are waiting for a Post.

Comment: How to I get both? The forms values and the parameter ? The first view `ResetPassword` is just to load the page.The request is made through the button.

Comment: Have you tried like this public ActionResult ResetPassword(string user, string hash)

Comment: if I do this, where I would receive the form data?There's a Model there!

Comment: @LaxmanGite I did this, Request.Form["oldpassword"]; and I get the value! I was worried about the model, but I found this way! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you haven't defined related parameters in your action because you are passing two parameters from **URI** :

```
user = "AAAAA", hash = "HASHVALUE"

var URL = new Uri( Url.Link("Default", new { Controller = "Reset", Action = 
"ResetPassword",user = "AAAAA", hash = "HASHVALUE" }));
```

***So you have to define you action according to that like*** :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(string user, string hash)
{
   var user = user;     
   var hash = hash;

   return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a HttpPost try to use a Get method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(string user, string hash)
{
   //populate the model with the user and hash values
   var model = new ResetUserModel();
   model.User = user;
   model.Hash = hash;
   return View(model);
}
```

You will be able to invoke the `ResetPassword` with your link:

```
http://localhost:52494/Reset/ResetPassword?user=BBBBBBBB&hash=AAAAAAA
```

Comment: the answer above worked! Like, when the ActionResult ResetPassword is called I need to have not just the parameter but the Form values too.. user,hash,oldPassword,password,repeat..

Comment: @NathielBarros I am glad that it worked for you, but if you want to pass the model to your view, you will need a proper implementation of the `ResetPassword` method. I have added a complete example. Cheers!